# ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs during Biclustering

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to model biclustering, but it's failing as it says array contains `infs` and `nans`, though I scanned array using `pd.isnull(DataFile).sum()`

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 from sklearn.datasets import samples_generator as sg
 from sklearn.cluster.bicluster import SpectralCoclustering
 from sklearn.metrics import consensus_score
 DataFile=pd.read_csv("DatafilledProp.csv",sep='\t')


 DataFile.drop(DataFile.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
 plt.matshow(DataFile.as_matrix(), cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
 plt.title("Original TransMapping")
 data, row_idx, col_idx = sg._shuffle(DataFile.as_matrix(), random_state=0)
 plt.matshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
 plt.title("Shuffled dataset")
 plt.show()
 Features=DataFile.values
 model = SpectralCoclustering(n_clusters=10, random_state=0)
 model.fit(Features)
```

This is the error that I get:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1 06, in exec_file
exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
     ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
     2, in exec_code
         exec(code_obj, global_variables)
       File "D:\ClusteringDemo\DataPreparation.py\DataPreparation.py\Model.py", line
     19, in <module>
         model.fit(Features)
       File "C:\Users\vinay.sawant\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages
     \sklearn\cluster\bicluster\spectral.py", line 126, in fit
         self._fit(X)
       File "C:\Users\vinay.sawant\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages
     \sklearn\cluster\bicluster\spectral.py", line 275, in _fit
         u, v = self._svd(normalized_data, n_sv, n_discard=1)
       File "C:\Users\vinay.sawant\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages
     \sklearn\cluster\bicluster\spectral.py", line 139, in _svd
         **kwargs)
       File "C:\Users\vinay.sawant\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages
     \sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 299, in randomized_svd
         Q = randomized_range_finder(M, n_random, n_iter, random_state)
       File "C:\Users\vinay.sawant\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages
     \sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 226, in randomized_range_finder
         Q, R = linalg.qr(Y, mode='economic')
       File "C:\Users\vinay.sawant\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages
     \scipy\linalg\decomp_qr.py", line 127, in qr
         a1 = numpy.asarray_chkfinite(a)
       File "C:\Users\vinay.sawant\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages
     \numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 613, in asarray_chkfinite
         "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
     ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
     Press any key to continue .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.isnull(DataFile).sum()` only checks for `NaN` values, as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[np.NaN,6]])

df
Out[12]: 
    0  1
0   1  2
1   3  4
2 NaN  6

pd.isnull(df).sum()
Out[13]: 
0    1
1    0
dtype: int64
```

But it will not check for `inf`, according to the error it's a possibility.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[np.inf,6]])

pd.isnull(df3).sum()
Out[23]: 
0    0
1    0
dtype: int64
```

Therefore, I suspect the error is an `inf` rather than `NaN`.

```
import numpy as np

np.isinf(df3).sum()
Out[25]: 
0    1
1    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

**This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764378/2649309**

> It could be problem with PCA implementation in scikit-learn 0.18.1.
>
> See a bug report
>   https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7568
>
> Described workaround is to use PCA with svd_solver='full'. So try this
>   code:

```
pipe = [('pca',PCA(whiten=True,svd_solver='full')),
   ('clf' ,lm)]
```

I was able to fix my issue with this.