# PCA in Sklearn - ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to use grid search to choose the number of principal components of the data before fitting into a linear regression. I am confused how I can make a dictionary of the number of principal components I want. I put my list into a dictionary format in the param_grid parameter, but I think I did it wrong. So far, I have gotten a warning about my array containing infs or NaNs.

I am following the instructions from pipelining a linear regression to PCA: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_digits_pipe.html

ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

I was able to get the same error on a reproducible example, my real dataset is the larger:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'C' : pd.Series(1, index = list(range(8)),dtype = 'float32'),
                     'D' : np.array([3] * 8,dtype = 'int32'),
                     'E' : pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train",
                     "test", "train", "test", "train"])})

df3 = pd.get_dummies(df2)

lm = LinearRegression()

pipe = [('pca',PCA(whiten=True)),
         ('clf' ,lm)]

pipe = Pipeline(pipe)


param_grid = {
    'pca__n_components': np.arange(2,4)}

X = df3.as_matrix()

CLF = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid = param_grid, verbose = 1, cv = 3)

y = np.random.normal(0,1,len(X)).reshape(-1,1)

CLF.fit(X,y)

ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

**EDIT: I put in the y for the fit statement, but it still gave me the same error. However, this was for my dataset NOT the reproducible example.**

Comment: Can you please run `np.any(np.isnan(X_mat))` and tell me the return value?

Comment: On my dataset, it returns  'False'

Answer (score 9):

I could be problem with PCA implementation in `scikit-learn 0.18.1.`

See a bug report https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7568

Described workaround is to use PCA with `svd_solver='full'`.
So try this code:

```
pipe = [('pca',PCA(whiten=True,svd_solver='full')),
       ('clf' ,lm)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I wrote.  It seems to work for me.  Notice that when you are calling `fit`, you need to provide it with training data (i.e a Y vector).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV



df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'C' : pd.Series(1, index = list(range(8)),dtype = 'float32'),
                     'D' : np.array([3] * 8,dtype = 'int32'),
                     'E' : pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train",
                     "test", "train", "test", "train"])})

df3 = pd.get_dummies(df2)

lm = LinearRegression()

pipe = [('pca',PCA(whiten=True)),
         ('clf' ,lm)]

pipe = Pipeline(pipe)


param_grid = {
    'pca__n_components': np.arange(2,4),
}

X = df3.as_matrix()

CLF = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid = param_grid, verbose = 1, cv = 3)

y = np.random.normal(0,1,len(X)).reshape(-1,1)

CLF.fit(X,y)

print(CLF.best_params_)
```

The print statement will show you the best `n_components`.  Without a y, you can't calculate the RSS, and wont be able to tell what is "best".

Comment: Thank you @Demetri P, you're right I did not include the y for GridsearchCV. I was trying to use the fit parameter for PCA instead of GridsearchCV. However, I was trying to fit the ymatrix in my dataset (but it works in my reproducible example), but still got the same error. I will put the edit in

Comment: @ScottDavis Hmm, that is tough.  I'm afraid I am out of ideas on this one.